# Subquery - Find duplicates that have different ID - Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, duplicates

I have a table that has a list of license numbers. A license number is assigned to an `ID`, and an `ID` can have multiple licenses of the same number (some are expired or different types etc).

Some license numbers have a 'B' on the front of the number. If I were to remove the 'B' I want to know how many license #'s get duplicated to DIFFERENT ID's.

So far I have stripped of the B and gotten the counts but now I need to go further and only query out whats being duplicated between ID's.

SQL

```
SELECT 
COUNT(*), TININDIV_IS_NUMBER as ID,
CASE
    WHEN SUBSTR (LICENSE_NO, 1, 1) <> 'B'
    THEN LICENSE_NO
    ELSE SUBSTR(LICENSE_NO, 2, LENGTH(LICENSE_NO)) 
END AS LICENCSE_NO
FROM BF_CERTIFICATE 
GROUP BY TININDIV_IS_NUMBER, LICENSE_NO
```

OUTPUT EXAMPLE
[image: results_output]

Comment: What result set do you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to know how many license #'s get duplicated to DIFFERENT ID's.

You can get the list of license #s as:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN SUBSTR (LICENSE_NO, 1, 1) <> 'B'
             THEN LICENSE_NO
             ELSE SUBSTR(LICENSE_NO, 2, LENGTH(LICENSE_NO)) 
        END) AS LICENCSE_NO,
       COUNT(DISTINCT TININDIV_IS_NUMBER)
FROM BF_CERTIFICATE 
GROUP BY (CASE WHEN SUBSTR (LICENSE_NO, 1, 1) <> 'B'
               THEN LICENSE_NO
               ELSE SUBSTR(LICENSE_NO, 2, LENGTH(LICENSE_NO)) 
          END) 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT TININDIV_IS_NUMBER) >= 2;
```

Note:  The `CASE` expression needs to be repeated in the `GROUP BY` because Oracle does not recognize column aliases in `GROUP BY` clauses.

If you want the actual count, then just use the above as a subquery and put a `count(*)` in the outer query.

Comment: Thank you @gordon - this appears to give me exactly what I need

Answer (score 0):

> I want to know how many license #'s get duplicated to DIFFERENT ID's

You can use two levels of aggregation to get the count of duplicates:

```
select count(*)
from (
    select 1
    from bf_certificate 
    group by case
        when substr (license_no, 1, 1) <> 'b'
        then license_no
        else substr(license_no, 2, length(license_no)) 
    end
    having count(*) = 1
) t
```

If you want the list of duplicated licence numbers, then one level of aggregation is enough:

```
select 
    case
        when substr (license_no, 1, 1) <> 'b'
        then license_no
        else substr(license_no, 2, length(license_no)) 
    end license_no,
    count(*)
from bf_certificate 
group by case
    when substr (license_no, 1, 1) <> 'b'
    then license_no
    else substr(license_no, 2, length(license_no)) 
end
having count(*) = 1
```